# animation does not disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario like this: 
when you click another div would come up and show waiting animation and it works properly but 
when I want it disappear it does not work here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


$('#t').hide();
$("#clickme").click(function () {
    $("#t").fadeIn(4000, function () {
        // Animation complete
        $("#t").show();
    });
});
setTimeout(

}, 5000);
$("#t").fadeOut(4000, function () { 
    $("#t").hide();
 });
});
```

and fiddle link is as follow: http://jsfiddle.net/hminaee/qF8dX/1/

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)** here instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#t').hide();
    $("#clickme").click(function () {
        $("#t").fadeIn(4000, function () {
            $("#t").show().delay(4000).fadeOut(1000);
        });
    });
});
```

So basically, after showing your waiting animation, it'll delay 4 seconds then fade out your waiting animation in 1 second.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qF8dX/3/)**

---

Based on your comment, you can add `pointer-events: none` to your modal to allow click event go through the modal:

```
.modal {
    pointer-events: none; 
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qF8dX/10/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot for your awesome answer but in the following scenario when I want it stopped when user click on div1 it is not working what is the problem with this :  jsfiddle.net/hminaee/qF8dX/8

Answer (score 1):

This closely ties to your original code: 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/qF8dX/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#t').hide();
    $("#clickme").click(function () {
        $("#t").fadeIn(4000, function () {
            // Animation complete
        }).promise().done(function () {;
            $("#t").fadeOut(4000, function () {
                // Animation complete
                $("#t").hide();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your awesome answer but in the following scenario when I want it stopped when user click on div1 it is not working what is the problem with this : jsfiddle.net/hminaee/qF8dX/8